# Importing packages from the web into Eclipse Java EE IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to import the following packages into Eclipse Java EE IDE:
https://svn.win.tue.nl/repos/cpntools/AccessCPN/trunk/

I don't want to download all classes manually. Is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install SVN for Eclipse (e.g. Subclipse, Subversive, etc.) through Eclipse MarketPlace and connect to the project's SVN Directory and download the project from there (through Eclipse).